# Как поставить запятую в список чисел

Tags: python, excel

В excel есть список номеров. Прим.:100,200,300 и т.д. Все эти номера расположенны в 1 колонне. Мне нужно вывести эти номера списком, чтобы после каждого номера была запятая. Помогите чайнику. Пытался в python засунуть, но там без запятых никак.

Comment: a = (100 200 300 400, sep=',')  Что-то типо этого, но номеров очень много и они все без запятых, вот и хотел узнать как это можно сделать.

Comment: А кавычки? А что мешает sep сделать пробелом? А в блокноте сделать replace?

Comment: В питоне выдается ошибка при списке чисел без запятых, то есть то этого sep даже не доходит.

Comment: Суть вопроса в том, что имеются очень много номеров: 100 200 300 400 и т.д. и между ними нету запятых. Надо, чтобы между ними были запятые.

Comment: В блокноте сделать search-replace этой части c пробела на запятую (повторно пишу). Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Не выходит, т.к. список  берется с колонны. То есть после номера 100, следующая 200 идет со след строки.

Comment: Тогда замену возврата каретки в среде которая это поддерживает (например far manager). Или делайте транспонирование.

Answer (score 1):

Пример с использованием [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
In [374]: import pandas as pd    #  pip install pandas

In [375]: df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Temp\111.xlsx')

In [376]: df
Out[376]:
   col1               col2
0     1        100,200,300
1     2           12,13,14
2     3  9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1

In [377]: df['col2'].str.split(',')
Out[377]:
0                [100, 200, 300]
1                   [12, 13, 14]
2    [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

тоже самое в виде списка списков:

```
In [378]: df['col2'].str.split(',').tolist()
Out[378]:
[['100', '200', '300'],
 ['12', '13', '14'],
 ['9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1']]
```